# How to add or hide prop based on condition in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a header component where I have some props.

```
        <Header
              :next="gonext"
              :isSuccess
              ...
            />
    
    method: {
    isTshirt(){
    return this.productType ==='t-shirt'
    }
  }
```

How can I check if the above isTshirt condition is true then remove :next prop and it's value completely otherwise use that prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a conditional statement inside `next` prop

```
:next="(isTshirt()) ? gonext : undefined"
```

or you can put the conditional statement above in a computed property.

Comment: But will undefined remove prop fully r it will show some warning in the console about undefined?

Comment: may I ask why you want to hide the prop? Because what you can do is to go to your Header component and check if the prop `next` is `undefined` (or you don't need to), in that way, `next` is technically "hidden" because it is undefined, and to say that all props are "optional" by default.

Comment: Perhaps because a property with no value is different from no property at all (for css).